# playwright-python Is there a way to navigate pages with post_data?

Tags: playwright-python

I learned how to navigate pages using

```
page.goto('someurl')
```

Some pages need to send post data to browse but it seems there is no arguments for post method in goto funtion.

and then I tried this.

```
page.request.post(url='someurl', data={'paramname':value})
```

but it doesn't navigate, it just gives me response.

I think I don't fully understand about route too. I thought if I set post_data and method using `route.continue_(method="POST", post_data={'k':somevalue})`
but it seems not affect to page.goto funtion. (but when I print page.request.post_data, it prints the dictionary that I set in route.continue_)

I stuck from this point..
Is there a way navigate pages with post data with playwright-python?

Comment: What site are you trying to automate, and what goal are you trying to achieve on it? Are you trying to submit a form with `method="POST"`?

Comment: @ggorlen I can't tell the website sorry. My goal is making an automation for navigating pages and each pages have post data payloads. So it is like a submit a form with method="POST" but there is no form in the website.. I am thinking of using `page.evaluate()` to make a form with a submit button but I wish if there is another simple way.